# How can I send Discord embed with a POST request via Webhooks C#

Tags: c#, httprequest, embed, discord, webhooks

I'm trying to send a request to discord webhook with embed but im facing an error 
it says {"message": "Cannot send an empty message", "code": 50006}
I've tried this code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace testing
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                { "content", "test" },
                { "payload_json", "content\": \"Hello, World!\", \"tts\": false, \"embed\": { \"title\": \"Hello, Embed!\", \"description\": \"This is an embedded message." }
                };
            values.Add("file", "file contents");
            values.Add("embeds", "");
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

            var response = await client.PostAsync("Webhook_Here", content);

            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but have you considered using [Discord.Net](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net)? Personally I have only good things to say about that wrapper.

Comment: I did. But I found that its pretty slow and with posting request to webhook its faster and i need my program to be as fast as possible

Comment: I don't really see how/why it would be slow. (What do you consider slow? Few ms slower?) Maybe you were doing something wrong. Also, now that I took a look at your question, you seem to be missing a `}` and the end of the `embed` field. But other than that, I have no idea if your approach is right.

Comment: Even if its only few seconds its big difference in that kind of program, And I just rechecked I don't see any missing }

Comment: Few seconds you say? I'm having a hard time believing it would somehow be that much slower. Must be doing something wrong. And this is the missing brace I meant, doesn't seem right to me: https://i.imgur.com/CakBaAT.png

Comment: Can you show me how to send an embed with webhook with discord.net maybe we're not talking about same thing. And yeah u were right my bad

Comment: They have [a minimal example](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/blob/dev/samples/04_webhook_client/Program.cs) on their Github.